# JSP page shows fine in Eclipse preview, but shows blank page when run on server

Tags: jsp, maven, extjs

I have a `login.jsp` page wich includes ExtJS code.

[image: login.jsp source in Eclipse]

When I click *Preview* tab in Eclipse, then it works correctly and I can see the output of the page.

[image: login.jsp preview in Eclipse]

However, when I run the project on server, then I don't see anything, only a blank page. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the question is valid now but still..I will try to answer it

This is Maybe because all your variables are in Javascript. Extjs will run on client side

Javascript is executed at client side an hence no variable values are shown in Eclipse page.

if you want **to inspect javascript variables use firebug**.

If your code is JSP code(inside scriptlet <% %>) then you should be able to see it.